# Catch statement does not catch thrown error in debug mode in an async function

Tags: dart, flutter, try-catch

I do not know why catch statement does not catch thrown error when I debug the app.
This is the main function:

```
void main() async {
  final initialState = await persistor.load();
  bool logged = false;

  if (initialState.isLoggedIn) {
    logged = await initialState.silentlyLogin(); // <---- FUNCTION THAT THROWS ERROR
  }
  if (!logged) {
    initialState.logout();
  }
}
```

This is the `silentlyLogin` function of my State class:

```
Future<bool> silentlyLogin() async {
    try {
      await globals.googleSignIn.signInSilently();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

In debug the `googleSignIn.signInSilently` function thrown an error, in this part of code:

```
@override
  dynamic decodeEnvelope(ByteData envelope) {
    // First byte is zero in success case, and non-zero otherwise.
    if (envelope.lengthInBytes == 0)
      throw const FormatException('Expected envelope, got nothing');
    final ReadBuffer buffer = ReadBuffer(envelope);
    if (buffer.getUint8() == 0)
      return messageCodec.readValue(buffer);
    final dynamic errorCode = messageCodec.readValue(buffer);
    final dynamic errorMessage = messageCodec.readValue(buffer);
    final dynamic errorDetails = messageCodec.readValue(buffer);
    if (errorCode is String && (errorMessage == null || errorMessage is String) && !buffer.hasRemaining)
      throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage, details: errorDetails); // <------ HERE IS THE ERROR
    else
      throw const FormatException('Invalid envelope');
  }
```

In the debug mode, android studio blocks the app in the `throw PlatformException` line, but my catch statement is never catched, so my function always returns true.
While my catch statement is never catched.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is probably thrown in native code and not passed to Dart at all. Dart can't catch Java or ObjectivC/Swift exceptions. The plugin would need to catch it in Java, send a message to Dart and in Dart an artificial exception would need to be thrown.

See also

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17677
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19748
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28430